# \lstinputlisting for a normal text file?

Tags: listings, external-files, highlighting

sometimes im using `\lstinputlisting` to show some code examples in my pdf. Now I just would like to insert a normal textfile. Everything is fine, I like this box around my text and the numbers every line. I just dont like that some string are **bold**. It's something like this:

> 12345 123 3123 **3213H ABC12 AB** 88789

So strings are bold. Somehow. I'm using `\lstinputlisting{file.txt}`. 
How can I change that? I mean highlighting is fine for my code, that's great but in this file I dont want this. Any ideas?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Use package `filecontents` (see `texdoc filecontents`) to include an example file `file.txt`.

Comment: Do you want a caption with this listing? If not, you can just use `\input{file.txt}`.

Comment: If you want plain text, with the option for a box around it and line numbers, you might consider `fancyvrb`.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 39):

Perhaps you have set a language using `\lstset`. You can disable the language by using the empty language:

```
\lstinputlisting[language={}]{file.txt}
```

Comment: With `begin` and `end` this might look like: `\begin{lstlisting}[language={}]`